# WPF-How to reload the same page on click of Tree View Hyperlink

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application without using MVVM ,we write the code in code behind,in it I have a tree view with hyperlinks .I use the following code to swap between the pages

```
 private void MnuMain_RequestNavigate(object sender, 
    System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
        this.MainContent.Content = null;
        this.MainContent.Resources.Clear();
        this.MainContent.Navigate(e.Uri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
  }
```

MainContent is a frame in which i show the cliked page

If a page is clicked the code goes through above lines and then goes to the constructor of the page where InitializeComponent() is called .However if the link is clicked again the constructor in the clicked page is not called.I want to reload the page on click of the same link ,like how it is done in web forms.The page reloads if i swap between pages ,but if i click same link it doesnt reload.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution we have to use the below code ,which will call the constructor of the page again

```
this.MainContent.NavigationService.Refresh();
```

but it wont work if we follow it with   `this.MainContent.Navigate(e.Uri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);`

so in order to solve this

-In constructor create a property that will be used to store last clicked link

```
App.Current.Properties["lastclickedlink"] = "";
```

then

```
    private void MnuMain_RequestNavigate(object sender, 
        System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
                      this.MainContent.Content = null;
                    this.MainContent.Resources.Clear();
    
                    if (App.Current.Properties["lastclickedlink"].ToString() == e.Uri.ToString())
                    {
                        this.MainContent.NavigationService.Refresh();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.MainContent.Navigate(e.Uri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                                         
                    }
 App.Current.Properties["lastclickedlink"] = e.Uri.ToString();
    }
```